# Convert text to column

Tags: excel, vba

I use the command Get External Data to get data from another Excel file. The problem with the data is I cannot make operation like sum with the cells, because the type dismatch error. Because of that, I want to use the command Text to columns to convert each column, but there is a limitation to do this using VBA (recording a macro to each column). How can I change the data format, sometimes my code is shorter than I need and sometimes is longer than I need. In both cases I get an error when I execute the code. Now I am looking for a code that could adapt to a varying range of data in the columns. Something that I can do is loop limiting the size of data and convert each cell to the same type and run my VBA code to make my analysis. I am stucked with this, so I do not have any code to share here. Can someone help me?

I got something

```
Dim rng As Range

 For Each rng In Range("A:D").Columns
  rng.TextToColumns
Next rng
```

But, when I find some empty data, I got stuck. How to identity if a range is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the actual answer is, but the question got me owndering why the GetExternalData throws a type mismatch error, and I googled for a while, finding this:

*There appears to be no valid reason for the "Type Mismatch" error, it's just a eccentricity of Excel. If you start a new line in the array after you use a variable, it tends to make it happy. Thus reformating the procedure to look like this:*

`With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array( _
    Array("ODBC;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=H:\DATA" & Subdirectory & DataFile (DataFileNum)), _
    Array(";DefaultDir=H:\DATA" & Subdirectory), _
    Array(";DriverId=790;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeou t=5;")), Destination:=ActiveCell)`

*should fix your "Type Mismatch" error. I hope this is of benefit to someone.*

Found it [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/516-vba-programming-get-external-data.html).